# Can not find PostGIS extensions ( installed in a different directory ) and $libdir/postgis-2.3 in mac os

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, postgis

I'm using postgres in pycharm and it can't find the postGIS extensions. It is looking for them in: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/share/postgresql/extension/`

however, when I install PostGIS, it tells me that: `PostGIS extension modules are installed in: /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension`

Another issue (don't know if it is related to the first) is : `could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory`

Comment: How did you install PostGIS?

Comment: Did you execute CREATE EXTENSION command for postgis

Comment: i install it using homebrow

Comment: yes I did and I get this message: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.3": No such file or directory

Comment: You should reinstall postGIS to fix this error. In Ubuntu it would be: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.3`

Answer (score 7):

I noticed this issue after having upgraded from PostGIS 2.3.0 to 2.4.0.  My databases were still looking for 2.3.0 libraries when the 2.4.0 were installed.
  The solution was to individually update the databases to look for the 2.4.0 versions:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

[See **Upgrading PostGIS** section for further details](http://postgis.net/install/)

Comment: In my case I DID UPDATE the extension to 2.4, but when upgrading to PG10, it complained about a missing of libdir/postgis-2.3.
I found that exactly one FUNCTION postgis.geog_brin_inclusion_add_value was missed in the UPDATE and still referenced '$libdir/postgis-2.3'. Dont know yet if I want to just drop or alter it, but maybe this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I installed using Homebrew and ran into this same issue. Seems to be resolved after following instructions from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/problems-to-start-postgresql-with-postgis-after-upgrade-to-fedora-28-a-4175629479/#post5853352:

> Find where postgis-2.4.so is (e.g.
>   /database/postgresql/pgsql-10.0/lib/postgis-2.4.so) then create a
>   symbolic link to older name so for my example I'd do:

```
ln -s /database/postgresql/pgsql-10.0/lib/postgis-2.4.so /database/postgresql/pgsql-10.0/lib/postgis-2.3.so
```

For me, the fix was this exact command:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.5.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.3.so
```